# FFMpeg crashes on decoding MJpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mjpeg

I'm working with FFMpeg for decoding Mjpeg streams.
Recently I've bumped into access violation exceptions from FFMpeg, after investigating, I found that due to network packet drops, I'm passing to the FFMpeg a frame that might have "gaps" in it.
The FFMpeg probably crash since it jumps to a marker payload which doesn't exist in the frame's memory.

Any idea where I can find a mjpeg structure validator?
Is there any way to configure FFMpeg to perform such validations by itself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't really found an answer to the question.
Apparently, ffmpeg doesn't handle corrupted frames very well.
Decided to try a different 3rd party decoder instead of ffmpeg. For now, at least for Jpeg, it works faster and much more robust.

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to use Gstreamer here instead of ffmpeg and set "max-errors" property in jpegdec plugin to -1.

`gst-launch -v souphttpsrc location="http://[ip]:[port]/[dir]/xxx.cgi" do-timestamp=true is_live=true ! multipartdemux ! jpegdec max-errors=-1 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink`.

This takes care of the corrupt jpeg frames and continues the stream.